# Positive definite Hermitian form with same imaginary part

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Consider a complex vector space V,

if I decompose a Postive definite Hermitian form  (,) into real and imaginary part, i get
$$(v,w)=\lbrace v,w \rbrace +[v,w]i$$
How can I show that whenever two such herimitian form have equal imaginary part, the two forms are equal? 
Thanks in advance.

**My thoughts:** I try to make use of  a n dimension complex vector space has the same basis as n dimension real vector space has...

Comment: This follows directly from the fact that $(x,y)=\Im(y,ix)-i\Im(y,x)$, assuming that the inner product is anti-linear in its first argument.

Comment: Sorry, what is that J-like symbol?

Comment: It's an I, not J. It denotes the imaginary part of a complex number. If $z=a+ib$ where $a$ and $b$ are real, then $x=\Re(z)=\frac12(z+\overline{z})$ and $y=\Im(z)=\frac{1}{2i}(z-\overline{z})$.

Comment: Oh i see, is this fact means that the  hermitian form can be solely expressed by its imaginary part. So naturally the two hermitian form with equal imaginary part are equal? Am i think it right?

Comment: Yes and this is essentially how the [polarisation identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) is proved.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: In case it's useful for others: Note that if $(v,w) = v^\dagger H w = v^\dagger A w + i v^\dagger B w$ where $A = (H+H^\dagger)/2 = A^\dagger$ and $B = (H-H^\dagger)/(i2) = B^\dagger$ are the real and imaginary parts of $H=A+iB=H^\dagger$, it's *not* the case that $\{v,w\} = v^\dagger A w$, $[v,w]= v^\dagger B w$.  That is, $[\cdot,\cdot]$ determines $(\cdot,\cdot)$ but $B$ does not determine $H$.